# How to revert incremental update in pdf using PDFBOX?

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, pdfbox

How can we revert last incremental update done in a pdf using pdfbox ?

For e.g.
[Original document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TF5-peVfFFpPIdV3U4sEafc0sf9J9hr2)
[Signed document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g0bm88Gbfu9u2UTs9P3mhltEbkgbli5l)

When I digitally sign(certification signature) an original document using incremental save, I get a signed document. Upon inspecting the source of signed document, I could see that "%%EOF" is presenting 2 times. If I manually remove last "%%EOF" along with its content, I could see PDF returns to its initial state, which is very similar to original document.

How can I do this pragmatically ?

I am using PDFBOX v2.0.8

Best Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: There are more advanced approaches and there are less advanced ones. The least advanced one would be to simply search the offset of the second to last occurrence of `%%EOF` in your file and cut off thereafter. You should use an actual byte sequence search but some implementors get by with text search using a complete single byte encoding like ISO 8859-1. A more advanced approach would check whether that `%%EOF` actually could have been the end of a revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more advanced approaches and there are less advanced ones.

This is the most simple one: It searches the `%%EOF` marker and cuts off right thereafter. This might not be identical to the original previous revision because that marker may be followed by an optional end-of-line marker. Unless that previous revision is signed or linearized, though, the variant with the end-of-line marker and the one without are equivalent as PDF files.

For searching the `%%EOF` marker we use the `StreamSearcher` class from the twitter/elephant-bird project, cf. [this earlier stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48853508/1729265):

```
public List<Long> simpleApproach(InputStream pdf) throws IOException {
    StreamSearcher streamSearcher = new StreamSearcher("%%EOF".getBytes());
    List<Long> results = new ArrayList<>();
    long revisionSize = 0;
    long diff;
    while ((diff = streamSearcher.search(pdf)) > -1) {
        revisionSize += diff;
        results.add(revisionSize);
    }
    return results;
}
```

For copying only the desired number of bytes, we use the Guava `ByteStreams` class. (There are many alternatives, e.g. Apache Commons IO, but Guava happened to already be in my test project dependencies.)

```
List<Long> simpleSizes = null;
try (   InputStream resource = GET_DOCUMENT_INPUTSTREAM) {
    simpleSizes = simpleApproach(resource);
}

if (1 < simpleSizes.size()) {
    try (   InputStream resource = GET_DOCUMENT_INPUTSTREAM;
            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("previousRevision.pdf")) {
        InputStream revision = ByteStreams.limit(resource, simpleSizes.get(simpleSizes.size() - 2));
        ByteStreams.copy(revision, file);
    }
}
```

`GET_DOCUMENT_INPUTSTREAM` might be a `new FileInputStream(PDF_PATH)` or `new ByteArrayInputStream(PDF_BYTES)` or whatever means you have to repeatedly retrieve an `InputStream` for the PDF. In case of these examples (`FileInputStream`, `ByteArrayInputStream`) you can even re-use the same stream using `reset()`.